# Push-mark not working properly in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have problem with understanding the `push-mark` function. For instance, open an empty buffer, type some text, and executing `(print mark-ring t)` gives `nil` in the echo area. Then doing

```
(push-mark)
```

and again `(print mark-ring t)` gives still `nil` in the echo area. I thought that I would now see something in the mark-ring. Further, doing a new `(push-mark)` at this point, and then `(print mark-ring t)` shows that the previous mark is now inside the mark ring..

Comment: Which mode? I'm getting proper behavior in `fundamental-mode`. Also, I'm using `eval-expression` instead of `print`.

Comment: @abo-abo `M-x describe-mode` gives `text-mode` with enabled minor modes: `Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Auto-Fill Blink-Cursor File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Eclim
Global-Font-Lock Iswitchb Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Savehist
Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark`

Comment: See if you can reproduce with `emacs -q` and fundamental. It's likely that one of the minor modes does this.

Comment: @abo-abo I get the same behavior in fundamental mode.. When I open Emacs with `-q` option it still opens in `text-mode`, so I have to change manually to `fundamental-mode`

Comment: @abo-abo Still, in `fundamental-mode` I have the follwing enabled minor modes: `Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock Line-Number
Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark`

Comment: `emacs -q` C-x b `temp` RET will create a buffer in fundamental-mode. No minor modes at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a buffer is new, it has no current mark and mark operations will fail or do nothing. After placing a mark, perhaps with `C-SPC`, the mark-ring should do as you expected.

Apparently calling `(push-mark)` will create the mark if it doesn't exist, probably as an unintended side-effect.

Comment: I thought `(push-mark)` did place a mark in the mark ring.. So why isn't the mark ring showing anything after the first call to `push-mark`? (But after the second call to `push-mark`, there is something in the ring suddenly..)

Comment: No. `(push-mark)` pushes *the current mark*, if any, into the mark ring. If there is no current mark, it will not do that. You can test this by observing the value of the current mark (with `M-: (mark)`).

Comment: Ok.. So what happens after the first call to `push-mark`? Does it set the current mark or something? Because for the second call to `push-mark` then there must be a current mark..

Comment: Oh, now I see. The final piece of the puzzle is that calling `push-mark` will create a mark if there was none in the buffer, so that's why the second one succeeds.